# Updating the type of the field into 'nested' in elastic search creating new documents

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I have connected couchbase document to the elastic search. I want to updated the type of a field in the each documents into nested type.So that i can search using nested filter. I tried with following mappings.

```
 curl -XPOST localhost:9200/dooht/couchbaseDocument -d 

 {"mappings":{"doc":{"properties":{"services":{"type":"nested","properties":{"name":{"type":"string"},"amount{"type":"long"}}}}}}}
```

But it is creating a new document with a new _id. I am new to the elastic search. Any idea about how to set a nested type field  in the existing document.

Comment: Do you want to update the existing field or create a new nested field?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a mapping with `dooht` as index and `doc` as type, you can use

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/dooht" -d "{\"mappings\":{\"doc\":{\"properties\":{\"services\":{\"type\":\"nested\",\"properties\":{\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"amount\":{\"type\":\"long\"}}}}}}}"
```

See references [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping)